# Storing iframe's id in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I was looking for a code like to store iframe's id in javascript's variable inside different divs.

```
   <div id="player">
       <iframe id="SAR7KmiCHto" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/SAR7KmiCHto?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>
   <div id="player2">
       <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9P9JSgZwrjc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="9P9JSgZwrjc"></iframe>
   </div>
```

In above code there are two div ids i.e player and player2. Now I want to store id of iframe from player div in javascript/jquery variable. Need some suggestions.

Comment: how? can you show me with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jQuery [**.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function

```
var ids = new Array();
$('div[id^=player] iframe').each(function()
     {
       ids.push($(this).attr('id'));                             
      })

console.log(ids); // output iframe's id array ["SAR7KmiCHto", "9P9JSgZwrjc"]
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/L6xsso3t/4/

Answer (score 0):

1) include jquery

2) include this js code

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var iframeID1 = $('#player iframe').attr('id');
    var iframeID2 = $('#player2 iframe').attr('id');
    $('#save_iframeID1').text(iframeID1);
    $('#save_iframeID2').text(iframeID2);
  });
</script>
```

in html

```
<div id="save_iframeID1"></div>
<div id="save_iframeID2"></div>
```

see

### [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ds2Lefq5/7/)

Comment: while alering iframeID1, it give undefined

Answer (score 0):

`iframe_ids = $("iframe[id]")` will get you a list of iframe elements with id's in jQuery
then you can get the id using `iframe_ids[n].id`